# Put data in matrix form

Tags: bash

I can't think of a way to do this in a bash shell and am ready to do it in C. But maybe you guys have a clever trick... I have two columns of X/Y position and a column of data and I'd like to keep only the data in a matrix form.

Example:

```
0 0 A
1 0 B
2 0 C
0 1 D
1 1 E
2 1 F
0 2 G
1 2 H
2 2 I
0 3 J
1 3 K
2 3 L
```

should become:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
J K L
```

(or its transposition, I don't care).
I don't know the name of this operation, but basically, when the 2nd column changes value, there should be a new line.

Comment: `tr -d '[0-9]'  < inputfile |xargs -l3`  is this you want ?

Comment: Yes, I can know beforehand the number of columns, so that'd work. Incredibly simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One with `cut`and `pr`:

```
$ cut -d ' '  -f 3 test|pr -3 -a -t -s' '
A B C
D E F
G H I
J K L
```

- `cut` with `' '` delimiter print only 3rd column.
- `pr` `-3` columns, `-a` across rather than down, `-t` suppress headers and footers, `' '` separator

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using awk:

```
$ awk 'p==$2&&s{s=s OFS $3;next}s{print s}{s=$3;p=$2}END{print s}' file
A B C
D E F
G H I
J K L
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your format is "row column value" and generalizing your
problem to a random stream of data, where the row and columns
positions do not arrive in a particular order, you may try this script

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A values  # parameter "values" is an "A"rray
rmax=0 cmax=0      # initial count of rows and columns

# read from standard input 3 values per line
while read r c v ; do
    # store the value just readen
    values[$c,$r]=$v
    # possibly update the final number of rows and columns
    [ $r -gt $rmax ] && rmax=$r
    [ $c -gt $cmax ] && cmax=$c
done

# double do loop on rows and columns, swap cycles if you prefer the transpose
for r in `seq 0 $rmax` ; do
    for c in `seq 0 $cmax` ; do
    # array parameters are undefined if not assigned,
    # it is possible to assign a def value using the ":-" syntax
    # in parameter substitution
        printf "%5s" ${values[$c,$r]:-"----"}
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

If you don't like the dashes, just use `printf "%5s" ${values[$c,$r]}`

*Example of usage*

```
$ echo '0 2 e
3 1 f
1 0 g' | ./the_script
 ---- ----    e
    g ---- ----
 ---- ---- ----
 ----    f ----
$
```